# How to delete photos from camera roll in iphone using phonegap file api?

Tags: iphone, cordova, fileapi

Actually I could delete the files from a location like below

```
/Users/manu/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
```

But the image is still visible in Photos app. From where is this coming?

How to make a picture available no where in the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete files outside of the sandbox of your app.
Thus you can't delete photo's from the device.

Comment: Is it because it is phonegap? Is there a native plugin for phonegap for this? Can we do it with titanium?

Comment: No all apps are sandboxed, even native ones. You can access any files outside of you apps sandbox, only via de SDK methods can you access files like photo, music and contacts. But there is not file system access.